Read from circular FIFO(Buffer) in C language
I have a hardware that writes input data to an address by hardware
The base address or starting circular FIFO is similar to this address 0xc6dc9cf0
Buffer(FIFO) Baseaddress
and has a register for circular buffer settings
Buffer(FIFO) Setting register
and has a pointer to write to the Circular FIFO and a pointer to read from the Circular FIFO
The write pointer is incremented by the hardware with each write.
Read and write pointer registers
Please see the pictures
An interrupt is called when the size of the write pointer exceeds the set limit
how read from Circular FIFO without overlapping?
I use the following code, but it doesn't work well and sometimes wrong data is written from the memory in the file, and this part of the data was not written in the memory by the hardware.
Note:write pointer return to zero if write pointer >= BUFFER_MAX_SIZE+16
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/completion.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/dmaengine.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>
#include <linux/iommu-helper.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/vmalloc.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <net/sock.h>

#define TSC_BASE_ADDRESS    0x01C06000
#define TSG_BASE_ADDRESS    0x01C06040
#define TSF_BASE_ADDRESS    0x01C06080
#define TSD_BASE_ADDRESS    0x01C06180

#define BUFFER_MAX_SIZE     1048576
void __iomem* tscBaseAddress;

volatile u8 *bufferBaseAddress;

volatile u32 *TSF_CBWPR;
volatile u32 *TSF_CBRPR;
volatile u32 *TSF_CBBAR;
volatile u32 *TSF_CBSZR

volatile int flag=0;
volatile int record_flag=1;
volatile int read_pointer;
volatile int write_pointer;

int fbuffer_len=0;
unsigned long long offset=0;
struct file *f;

struct task_struct *thread_st;

int thread_fn(void *unused) 
{
    int i=0,len;
    unsigned char *fbuffer=kmalloc(BUFFER_MAX_SIZE+16,GFP_KERNEL);
    while (record_flag)
    {
        while(!flag){};
        flag=0;
        len=write_pointer-read_pointer;
        if(len<0)
            len=(BUFFER_MAX_SIZE-read_pointer)+write_pointer;
        fbuffer_len=len;
        while(len>0)
        {
            fbuffer[i++]=*(bufferBaseAddress+read_pointer);
            len--;
            read_pointer++;
            if(read_pointer>=(BUFFER_MAX_SIZE+16))
                read_pointer=0;
        }
        *TSF_CBRPR=read_pointer;
        file_write(f,offset,fbuffer,fbuffer_len);
        offset+=fbuffer_len;
        i=0;
    }
    record_flag=1;
    return 0;
}

static irqreturn_t tsc_irq_handler(int irq,void *dev_id) 
{
    read_pointer  = *TSF_CBRPR;
    write_pointer = *TSF_CBWPR;
    *TSF_DISR=0x00000001;//clear interrupt
    flag=1;
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int tsc_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    u32 tmp;
    unsigned long value;
    tscBaseAddress = ioremap(TSC_BASE_ADDRESS, 4096);
    if (tscBaseAddress == NULL)
    {
        printk("Failed to map memory to TSC\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    TSF_CBBAR     = (volatile u32 *)(tscBaseAddress+0x80+0x50);
    TSF_CBSZR     = (volatile u32 *)(tscBaseAddress+0x80+0x54);
    TSF_CBWPR     = (volatile u32 *)(tscBaseAddress+0x80+0x58);
    TSF_CBRPR     = (volatile u32 *)(tscBaseAddress+0x80+0x5C);
    
    printk("TSC Successfully mapped in memory\n");
    
    ret = request_irq(113, tsc_irq_handler, IRQ_NONE, "TSC Driver", (void *)(tsc_irq_handler));
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "%s: request_irg failed with %d\n",__func__, ret);
    }
    printk("IRQ TSC done\n");
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printk("TSF_CBWPR:%x\n",*TSF_CBWPR);
    *TSF_CBWPR=0x00000000;
    mdelay(100);
    printk("TSF_CBWPR:%x\n",*TSF_CBWPR);
    
    printk("TSF_CBRPR:%x\n",*TSF_CBRPR);
    *TSF_CBRPR=0x00000000;
    mdelay(100);
    printk("TSF_CBRPR:%x\n",*TSF_CBRPR);

    printk("TSF_CBSZR:%x\n",*TSF_CBSZR);
    *TSF_CBSZR=0x02100000;
    mdelay(100);
    printk("TSF_CBSZR:%x\n",*TSF_CBSZR);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printk("TSF_CBBAR:%x\n",*TSF_CBBAR);
    value=(*TSF_CBBAR);
    bufferBaseAddress     = (volatile u8 *)(value);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    thread_st = kthread_run(thread_fn, NULL, "my_kthread");
        if (IS_ERR(thread_st)) 
    {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Error creating thread\n");
            return PTR_ERR(thread_st);
        }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Kernel Thread Created\n");
    f=file_open("/root/Desktop/a.ts",O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (IS_ERR(f)) 
    {
            printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to create file: %ld\n", PTR_ERR(f));
            return PTR_ERR(f);
        }
    printk("Create file ok\n");
    offset=0;
    return 0;
}

static void tsc_exit(void)
{
    free_irq(113,(void *)(tsc_irq_handler));
    if (client_socket) 
        sock_release(client_socket);
        if (listen_socket) 
        sock_release(listen_socket);
    flag=1;
    record_flag=0;
    file_close(f);
}


Please edit your question and add a tag for the coding language. This will help get the right people to see this post. It would also be helpful if you provided an example of the "wrong data" that's written and then explain what you expect to happen instead.

"I use the following code ..." - Why is this code written with inconsistent style? How many people wrote this code? Try learning kernel code style. Calling ioremap() without first calling request_mem_region() is bad practice. You fail to initialize both read_pointer and write_pointer in tsc_init().  In tsc_irq_handler() updating the read pointer seems to make no sense.

To add to @sawdust comment: in a few lines the printk() is used with and without log level…

How can you be sure a file_write will complete before the buffer fills?

The buffer size is 1MB and an interrupt occurs when the buffer is 1/8 full, I don't think this will cause a problem.

A busy loop such as while(!flag){}; is really bad code. Use a semaphore instead.

how use semaphore for this project?

There are many design issues in this driver.
The initialization of your driver is incoherent. The thread which uses the output file is created before the file is opened.
The synchronization based on the setting of the global flag variable between the thread and the ISR is hazardous. You can't assume that the the setting and the checking of the variable is atomic. So, many issues can occur. Some examples:

While the thread is running its loop using read_pointer & write_pointer, the ISR may be triggered and modify them in parallel;
When the ISR sets flag to 1, the thread may be running at the line just before setting the flag to 0. So, it will not see the flag set to 1.

You should use the work queue API which makes the ISR trigger a function to do the reading and logging of the incoming data.
